# Does such function sequences always exists converging subsequence to original function a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Function sequences $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{f_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ satisfies
$$
f_n\rightarrow f \ \  pointwise \ \ a.e.  (n\rightarrow\infty)
$$

$$
\forall n, \  f_{n,k} \rightarrow f_n \ \ pointwise \ \ a.e. (k\rightarrow \infty)
$$
Does it always exists such indexes $\{k_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that satisfies
$$
f_{n,k_n}\rightarrow f \ \ pointwise \ \ a.e. (n\rightarrow \infty)
$$
($a.e.$ in the sense of Lebesgue measure)

PS: I understand that we can prove the proposition above if $\{f_{n,k}\}$ are measureable for arbitrary n,k, by using Egorov's theorem for 'every converging series is uniformly converging a.e.', but I failed to reach further.

I tried to find a counterexample because the condition seems weak; however, since I have been studying real analysis not for long, I am not familiar with non-measurable functions and their limits yet.

Any information that helps is appreciated, and thanks in advanced!

**Edit 1:** I also considered another version of the proposition, in which we deletes all a.e. condition. This isn't strong relevant to the original one, but is there any insight from it? :)